# Load variable from file and compare

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a ansible script to add a iptable rule by checking if the rules already exist.

In the script, I save all the iptables result to a variable "ipall". Then I read the new rules in "rules.txt" and save it to rules variable. Now I'm trying to take the first rule from "rules.txt" and verify if the rules exist in the ipall, if not then add it to iptables.

```
  tasks:
    - name: fetch iptable
      shell: iptables-save
      register: ipall

    - debug: var=ipall

    - name: load variables
      command: cat rules.txt
      register: rules

    - debug: var=rules

    - name: search a rule
      debug:
        msg: "iptables {{ item }}"
      loop: rules.stdout_lines
      when: item not in ipall.stdout_lines
```

```
[root@localhost myplaybooks]# cat rules.txt 
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 100 -j ACCEPT
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 101 -j ACCEPT
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 102 -j ACCEPT
```

I expect the script to add the rules in rules.txt, instead i get the following error.

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=rules.stdout_lines) => {
    "msg": "iptables rules.stdout_lines"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the when clause without the braces? `ipall.stdout_lines.find(rules) == -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below is working:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    rules: "{{ lookup('file', 'rules.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: fetch iptable
      shell: iptables-save
      register: ipall
    - debug:
        var: ipall.stdout_lines
    - debug:
        var: rules
    - name: search a rule
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ipall.stdout_lines }}"
      when: item not in rules
```

file -->

```
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 100 -j ACCEPT
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 101 -j ACCEPT
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 102 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
```

partial output -->

```
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP) => {
    "msg": "-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN)
ok: [localhost] => (item=-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN) => {
    "msg": "-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=COMMIT) => {
    "msg": "COMMIT"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=# Completed on Fri Jun 21 17:07:15 2019) => {
    "msg": "# Completed on Fri Jun 21 17:07:15 2019"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks error404. Loading file into variables helped. But the search task was working opposite. I modified the task as below and it is doing what I was expecting.
```
rules: "{{ lookup('file', 'rules.txt') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: fetch iptable
      shell: iptables-save
      register: ipall

    - name: search a rule
      shell: iptables {{ item }}
      with_items:
        - "{{ rules.splitlines() }}"
      when: item not in ipall.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see what will happen

```
- name: Print commands to apply missing rules
  debug:
     msg: "iptables {{ item }}"
  loop: rules.stdout_lines
  when: item not in ipall.stdout_lines
```

Then try the task below (with the TESTCHAIN first, of course)

```
- name: Search and apply missing rules
  command: "iptables {{ item }}"
  loop: rules.stdout_lines
  when: item not in ipall.stdout_lines
```

(not tested)

Comment: You should delete these comments and update the question. Make it [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show some effort to solve the problems especially when there is a hint on how to solve it in the error you post.